# initially undefined ng-model on a "new" form

Tags: angularjs

When I load a page to add a new product, the model mv.product is initially undefined, and is created only when I start modifying the ng-model directives values.

**Controller:**

```
function myController () {
    var vm = this;

    vm.saveProduct(product) {
        // save product who's properties were defined 
        // by the view's two way databindings

    }

}
```

**View:**

```
<input ng-model="vm.product.someProperty">
<button ng-click="vm.saveProduct(vm.product)">
```

Why not define the blueprint of the model in my controller ? like:

```
vm.product ={ /* properties and their initial values */}
```

Instead of designing the model through the view's data-bindings.

Comment: Why not define it? That _is_ the right way to do it. There's also the option of doing it via `ng-init` if you _want_ to do it via the HTML

Comment: you typically don't have defaults for most user input.....so why go to all that extra work?

Comment: @nikjohn that is not what ng-init is for...read the docs. And saying you usually do define all properties is not needed unless defaults are required in the app itself

Comment: `ng-init` _can_ be used for that. Like I said, the default way of doing this is via the controller. Or in your state definition, whatever works for you.

Comment: @nikjohn the docs advise against it ... follow the docs..and best practices. No need to put controller functionality in the view

Comment: I do realize that. That is why I said _if you want to do it via HTML_. I've updated my answer further with details about why you should be initializing via your controller

Answer (score 0):

For initializing `ng-model` values, there are two ways to go:

- Initialize the value in your controller like you've mentioned
- Use `ng-init` in your html `<input ng-model="smthn" ng-init="">`

**Ideally, you shouldn't be creating models in your views** according to Angular JS's best practices. Models should be created in the controller and then bound in the views. So the premise is kind of off. This is one of the reasons why you initialize the scope variables in the controller.